# CredSSP - How does it work?

Tags: powershell, authentication

Been trying to find a web site that lists the steps carried out to perform authentication - but to date have not found one.

The reason being is that it is broken. Get 500 server error and have not found a way of getting the remote machine (service provider) to give me detailed information as to what is going wrong
Created a root CA authority. created certificates.

Where should they be placed?
What are the parameters for them?

Answer (score 0):

> Been trying to find a web site that lists the steps carried out to perform authentication - but to date have not found one.

Start with: [PowerShell 2.0 remoting guide: Part 12 – Using CredSSP for multi-hop authentication](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/powershell-2-0-remoting-guide-part-12-%E2%80%93-using-credssp-for-multi-hop-authentication/). The author also published a [free book on PowerShell 2.0 remoting](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=22). See, if it helps, and if not - get back with more specific questions.